# Interpret and compare lasso models

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, glmnet

I'm using lasso logistic regression in order to identify important variables and make inferences. For that I deploy glmnet and repeated cross validation to identify the best tuning parameters lambda.

In the first step I build a model including only my control variables. 
In the second step I add other predictors and compare the selected variables, fit, and performance with the first model. Below are the measures of the two models.

controls (CV_error| % deviance): 1.320194 | 15.26

full model (CV_error| % deviance): 1.3705 | 14.97

I identify a best lambda for each of the two models (0.03|0.09). The first column measures the mean cross validation error in binomial deviance. The second column measures % of deviance explained compared to the intercept-only model when I fit the model on the whole data.

As far as I know I can use the first column to tell something about the predictive accuracy of the models. The second column can be used to tell something about the performance improvement of the model compared to the null model (comparable to R^2 in linear regression?).

As one can see, my full model doesn't perform better than the controls only model, despite other variables are being selected. Even when I create another model where I don't penalize the controls to keep them all in the model, one additional variable is selected by lasso.

What would you conlude?

Why is there no improvement in performance?

Are the predictors useful despite they don't improve the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking only at the CV error (I don't think a training-error figure like your "% deviance" is very helpful, especially for a penalized model like the lasso), I would conclude that, at least around your sample size, the predictors beyond the control variables aren't helpful for prediction. Adding them to the model only worsened predictive accuracy. So, they aren't useful.

*Why* they're not helpful for prediction is of course hard to guess at without knowing the context of this problem.

By the way, the right way to compare your models' predictive accuracy to that of a trivial model is not to look at training error, but to compute CV error for the trivial model.

Comment: thx for the answer, what exactly do you mean by compute CV error for the trivial model? I thought I did that by taking the CV error of both CV procedures.

Comment: By the trivial model, I mean a model that has no predictors, which I think is what you meant by "null model" above. In each round of CV, all it would do to predict the probability of a positive case in the test fold would be to regurgitate the proportion of positive cases it sees in all the training folds. Just compute the CV error for this model like you did for the other two models.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. The following paper used a measure on page 53 similar to my %deviance measure to assess overall model fit: Mitra, Gilbert (2014). The Language that Gets People to Give: Phrases that Predict Success on Kickstarter.

Comment: Look at table 2, I don't know why the authors didn't compute CV error for the intercept-only model, or why they only present a relative rather than absolute measure of CV error. Both omissions seem unhelpful.

Comment: My presumption is, because they also use glmnet, that the first column in table 2 is similar to my %deviance measure. Also it might be that one cannot do CV on the trivial model with glmnet.

Comment: In the meantime I implemented a relaxed lasso approach. Now my CV errors of the full model are better than the errors of the control model. 1.137127 compared to 1.195433. Do you know if I can test if that difference is significant?

Comment: No, I don't know. One doesn't usually use significance testing in this context.

Comment: Ok, good to know. So I just choose the one with lower value?

Comment: Ok I want to close this question shortly. I just wanted to add some more clarification at the end. My research goal is to find important variables that add additional power in terms of inference as well as prediction. To compare the predictive power I compare the cross validation error (binomial deviance). To asses the model fit (like R2 in linear regression) I want to compare the deviance (or Chi square) of the trivial model, the controls only model, and the full model on the complete data. Compare this explanation: http://www.link.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/CrossValidationFinal.pdf

Comment: "So I just choose the one with lower value?" — Yes.

Comment: Regarding including a measure of model fit alongside a measure of predictive accuracy, the author of that presentation does not seem to be fully aware that model fit and predictive accuracy can be at odds with each other, to the extent that the true data-generating model may be predictively worse than a simpler model (e.g.,: Domingos, P., & Pazzani, M. (1997). On the optimality of the simple Bayesian classifier under zero-one loss. *Machine Learning, 29*, 103–130. doi:10.1023/A:1007413511361). I think that rather than pursuing both, you should decide which you want.

Comment: Thx @Kodiologist, now I am aware and understand that both prediction and model fit are conflicting with each other. However, I shrunk my model and it seems that I probably found a solution where I indeed can achieve both. Better prediction in CV and a higher model fit. I don't build a complete predictive model neither do I want to completely overfit the data. I want to find variables that really explain a phenomena and be generalizable.

Comment: Again, thx for all the valuable input.